# Error in `[.simple_triplet_matrix`(matrix, totalSize, ) : subscript out of bounds

Tags: r

I am curently working on this tutorial : https://www.svm-tutorial.com/2014/11/svm-classify-text-r/

On step five it shows the following:

```
container <- create_container(dtMatrix, data$IsSunny, trainSize=1:11, virgin=FALSE)
```

It recursively shows this error:

> ```
> Error in `[.simple_triplet_matrix`(matrix, totalSize, ) : 
>   subscript out of bounds
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this to make sure the number of data in the dataframe data is equal or more than your training size.

**container <- create_container(dtMatrix, data$IsSunny, 
              trainSize=1:nrow(data), virgin=FALSE)**

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Double check the number of rows with data in your csv file. trainSize=1:"number of data rows". Also, check the column name.